# How to read nested dictionary created from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary from a panda table for fast access. However, I am unable to figure out how to access the elements and the key easily.

The dictionary is in the below format.

```
{'token': {'NIFTY22SEP2214100PE': '52263_NFO', 'NIFTY22SEP2214050PE': '52249_NFO'}, 
'o185': {'NIFTY22SEP2214100PE': True, 'NIFTY22SEP2214050PE': False}, 
'underlying': {'NIFTY22SEP2214100PE': 'NIFTY', 'NIFTY22SEP2214050PE': 'NIFTY'}, 
'instrument': {'NIFTY22SEP2214100PE': 'OPTIDX', 'NIFTY22SEP2214050PE': 'OPTIDX'}, 
'strike': {'NIFTY22SEP2214100PE': 14100, 'NIFTY22SEP2214050PE': 14050}}
```

Now I want to get the 'strike' for token value '52263_NFO'. Or if I want the 'token' value for 'NIFTY22SEP2214050PE' if only o185 is True.

How can I achieve that? I know I can split this into key, item and then again in key, item and then use list comprehension.

But wanted to know if there is a more elegant solution for this.

Comment: You may probably want to rethink conversion of DataFrame to dictionary

Comment: probably it would be faster, easier and more elegeant to use `DataFrame` instead of `dict`. OR you should reformat you `dict` to create more useful `dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary is called "dic", one thing you can do is :

```
token = [token for token in dic["token"] if dic["token"][token] == "52263_NFO"][0]

strike = dic["strike"][token]
```

You can adapt this lines for the 2nd question.